# Multiple links with the same class

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, jquery

I have multiple links using the same class on my page :

```
<a class="tweetAnswer" rel="link1" href="">Answer</a>
```

I'm trying to show an alert with jQuery when someone clicks on one of these links. Unfortunately it doesn't show anything on Firefox...

```
$('a.tweetAnswer').live("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.9? `live` method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and removed in jQuery 1.9, use `on` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

[live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) has been deprecated since 1.7 and removed in version 1.9. Try:

```
$('a.tweetAnswer').on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

edit: good catch by adeneo on the lack of an event parameter.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjGYn/)

Comment: @JeremyWagemans - check the jsfiddle link I added. Can you elaborate on how it isn't working?

Comment: Yes I saw but it is still not working. It's crazy... Working pretty well on webkit, nothing on FF. 
The 'repondre' link there : http://dev2.prysmradio.com/index.php

Comment: It comes from the fact that I dynamically create the links I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there is no event parameter:

```
$('a.tweetAnswer').live("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert( $(this).attr('rel') );
});
```

secondly, you should be using on() in jQuery 1.7 or newer:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.tweetAnswer', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert( $(this).attr('rel') );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Working pretty well on Safari/Chrome but nothing on FF. It would come from something else imo.

Comment: @JeremyWagemans - Both examples are delegated event handlers for dynamic elements, and there is nothing special with any of those, and they are pretty basic and should work in all browsers, especially firefox which rarely has problems with such event handlers.